# read SB message with azure functions service bus trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I just created a simple azure function using service bus trigger. I am using the default example provided. I can read the messageid in the  code below

```
public static void Run(string mySbMsg, TraceWriter log)
{
log.Info($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: 
{mySbMsg}");
}
```

I`m struggling to find codes showing how to read the json message that was posted.
Thanks for you help

Comment: Do you want to read the mySbMsg as Json format? Or you want to analyze the json message?

Comment: Here is an issue about receive JSON object from the azure service bus topic subscriptions, you could refer to [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006478/how-to-receive-json-object-from-the-azure-service-bus-topic-subscriptions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `BrokeredMessage` parameter to get the message body in Azure Function Service Bus Trigger.

This will return the message with the `BrokeredMessage.GetBody()` method.

Get more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus#trigger---usage).

In Azure portal, add "project.json" in View Files. This the library which contains BrokeredMessage object.

The project.json should look like

```
{
  "frameworks": 
    {  
      "net46":
      { 
        "dependencies":
        {
          "WindowsAzure.ServiceBus": "4.1.2"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

When you save, you can see the package gets restored.

Inside the Run method, add `BrokeredMessage` as parameter. The method should look like

```
public static void Run(BrokeredMessage message, TraceWriter log)
{
string messageBody = message.Properties["Message"].ToString();
string messageId = message.Properties["Id"].ToString();
log.Info($"message - " + messageBody + " Id " + messageId);
}
```

Don't forget to add `Using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging` in "Run.csx" and change the `name` property to message in "Function.json"

Comment: I get The type or namespace name 'BrokeredMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). I tried 
using Microsoft.ServiceBus; but it still fails

Comment: For functions of version 2.x you should use Message instead of BrokeredMessage

Comment: Can you please post a sample code for me ..the default one is      [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("mytopic", "mysubscription", Connection = "")]string mySbMsg, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {mySbMsg}");
        }
    }